# Creating a video keyboard in Processing and I have overlapping loops

Tags: processing

I don't know why I can't get my video keyboard to work. I've written my code so that when you press any key Processing will play a video randomly selected from the array.

```
//forum.processing.org/two/discussion/6590/play-a-random-list-of-videos-by-keypress-exhaust

boolean sketchFullScreen() {
  return true;
}

import processing.video.*;
String[] moviesNames = { 
  "1.mov", "2.mov", "3.mov", "4.mov","5.mov", "6.mov", "7.mov","8.mov", "9.mov", "10.mov","11.mov", 
  "12.mov", "13.mov","14.mov", "15.mov", "16.mov","17.mov", "18.mov", "19.mov","20.mov", "21.mov", "22.mov","23.mov","24.mov", "25.mov", "26.mov",
};
int index = int(random(moviesNames.length));

Movie[] movies;

//Movie mov_a, mov_b, mov_c, mov_d, nowPlaying;

Boolean isPlaying = false;

void setup() {
  size(displayWidth, displayHeight, P2D);
  background(0);
  frameRate = 60;
  movies = new Movie[moviesNames.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < moviesNames.length; i++) {
    movies[i] = new Movie(this, moviesNames[i]); 
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(0);

  if(isPlaying){
    image(movies[index], 0, 0, width, height);

  }
}


void movieEvent(Movie _mov) {
  _mov.read();
}

void keyPressed() {

  isPlaying = true;
  int k = keyCode;
  if (k >= 'A' && k <= 'Z'){
    pickRandomVideoIndex();
  }
}

void keyReleased(){
  isPlaying = false;
  movies[index].stop();
}


void pickRandomVideoIndex() {
  if (movies.length <= 1) {
    return;
  }
  //movies[index].pause(); // pause current video.

  int rnd = index; // keep picking a new index till got a diff. 1:
  while ( rnd == index ){
   rnd = (int) random(movies.length);
  }

  // assign newly picked random value to index:
  index = rnd;
  movies[index].loop(); // and start playing it.
}
```

I love some help in figuring out how to keep the videos from playing over each other when you press more than one key. Once you press more than one key at a time, or type really fast, all hell breaks loose.

Thanks, [here are my files](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3b9dbd16h5451w5/AABKuXfrmwgZ40opWlpkpPFva?dl=0).

Comment: What programming language is this? Tag it with the language and you will get more people viewing it. Also where is the program entry point?

Comment: @Jon The language is Processing. It is tagged.

Comment: What happens when you uncomment this line:

    //movies[index].pause(); // pause current video.